# Pyspark map function printing only 1st roe

Tags: dictionary, pyspark, foreach, user-defined-functions

df.rdd.map(printudf(row)) is printing only 1st row

Def printudf(row):
Print(row)

Df.rdd.foreach(printudf(row)) :> is giving stage failure after first row print

Comment: Please let me know if the following answer works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `foreach` instead of `map` if you just want to print

```
def printudf(row):
    print(row)


output_df.rdd.foreach(printudf)
```

Use map if you are applying some modification/transformation of each row and returning a new row.

Comment: Getting job aborted due to stage failure: error

Comment: What is the version of Spark you use and how many rows are there in the data frame.